# How to store a Json coming from Ajax in a global variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am not able to store a Json that I get through Ajax in Jquery in a global variable, it only works inside the function.

```
let ingJson;
let masasJson;
let salsasJson;

searchIngredients();
console.log(ingJson);
```

Here `log` throws me an `undefined` error when I need the Json returned to me so I can use it in the rest of the code.

```
function searchIngredients(){
    let origin = `/ingredientes.json`;
    $.get(origin).then(htmlIngredients);
}
function htmlIngredients(res){
    ingJson = res.ingredientes;
    masasJson = res.masas;
    salsasJson = res.salsas;
    console.log(ingJson);
}
```

Here `log` returns the Json correctly.

Answer (score -3):

Initially assign to empty array,

```
var ingJson = [];
```

Then check length and do whatever stuff you need.

Comment: An empty array isn't more useful than `undefined`.